# (Discord bot) How do I make a welcome msg when a user joins a discords server (discord.js)?

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I am making a discord.js bot and I want to make a welcome msg when someone joins the server.

Here is the basic layout I want:

input: &welcome_channel

get channel id.

input: &welcome_msg

then store this msg.

I have no idea how to get the channel and how to display the welcome message on said channel. Please help.

Comment: You should read the [discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome)

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Discord.js](https://discord.js.org) library you can use the [guildMemberAdd](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd) to run a function each time a user joins the server, this event also passes a [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object, using it you should be able to get the server that the user has joined, if there is one the default welcome channel for that server.